# Div size miscalculating using Orbit Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, css, plugins

i am using the jquery plugin Orbit and it works fine in FF. in chrome and safari it miscalculates the div size as 1px high and wide and applies it to the wrapper div.. so no photos show up.

is there something specific about the rendering engines that make it calculate correctly in one browser but not in another? I have set the style of the wrapper div in my stylesheet, but Orbit applies the style inline which overrides.

any suggestions would be appreciated. i have it running correctly here http://jsfiddle.net/j9zLe/ in all browsers, but the page i am using it on has a lot of other code on it. i think it must be some style further up the chain... but not sure what to look for.

thanks Liz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jquery.orbit-1.2.3.js file on line 52 is the following line:

```
orbit.add(orbitWidth).width('1px').height('1px');
```

I'm not sure of the point of this line however if you change the width and height values to the values for your slides or comment-out the line I'm fairly sure it will fix your problem.

In your jsfiddle you need to add a resource for the JavaScript and CSS files for Orbit to make it render properly.

Comment: so i tried that and then it worked in safari but tanked in firefox. the cycle stopped functioning. sorry the fiddle works now, i had it hooked to a server you need to log into and forgot.

Comment: i commented out the line and it now works in both BUT in safari the timer is normal and in FF it goes super super slow... safari is about 4 times as fast.

Comment: What happens when you leave the line in and change the values to the actual dimensions of your slideshow (this was what fixed it for me however I don't use the timer because it messes with the timing of the slideshow too much on slow CPU's)?

Comment: when i just replace the values then it doesnt work in firefox. i had to comment it out. the timer thing is weird. same CPU for both browsers. it seems like in FF the timer setting is being ignored. when i make it faster or slower...i only see the change in safari

Comment: The `startClock()` function starts on line 99 and goes to line 131. If you are interested in how the timer is run for this plugin there's where to look.